# Gatsby: how to apply CSS to gatsby-image

Tags: css, gatsby

I'm trying to apply CSS to gatsby-image. Gatsby keeps rendering HTML which doesn't have the styling applied.

In this example I'm trying to apply a `transition: 3s`:

```
<Picture ... className="test" style={{ transition: '3000ms'; }}/>
<style jsx>{`
     .test img {
         transition: 3000ms !important;
     }
     .test picture {
         transition: 3000ms !important;
     }
     img {
         transition: 3000ms !important;
     }
     picture {
         transition: 3000ms !important;
     }
     ...
```

When I open the rendered page in browser, I can see in devtools that the `<Picture>` tag was generated into:

```
<div class="test gatsby-image-wrapper" ...>
    <img ...> // placeholder SVG
    <picture ... <img...>> // actual image with what I believe is img fallback for older browsers
```

When I select any of those 3 elements, I can see the `transition` is set to 0.5s, even though I set it to 3s in multiple places.

[Here](https://github.com/baobabKoodaa/blog/blob/cssProblem/src/components/Article/ReImage.js) is the complete code needed to demonstrate the problem. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gqza7.jpg) is a screenshot showing that the CSS is not applied.

Comment: I can't reproduce this, I copied exactly what you post here onto a project I'm working on and it's [working as expected](https://imgur.com/a/cJI39tq)

Comment: Okay good to know, that means something else in my project might be causing this. I added a screenshot and the complete code to OP.

Answer (score 1):

In Gatsby they have their own structure to create images for optimizing results as much as possible, therefore if you want to add custom styles to your image, image's wrapper, or placeholder you should use:

```
import Img from 'gatsby-image'

<Img style="<wrapper's_style_comes_here>" imgStyle="<img_style_comes_here>" placeholderStyle="<placeholder_style_comes_here>" .../>
```

for more, please checkout Gatsby's image plugin [website](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-image/).